# apt-get or dpkg unpack problems

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm having problems updating Libreoffice on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. There's an unmet dependency on libreoffice-common but when I run sudo apt-get install -f I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libreoffice-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 76.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice-common.
(Reading database ... 118950 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/sg36.sdg.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir: failed to remove â/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/â: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove â/var/lib/libreoffice/share/â: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove â/var/lib/libreoffice/program/â: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove â/var/lib/libreofficeâ: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove â/var/lib/libreofficeâ: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu5.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm guessing dpkg is having problems unpacking the deb file? I've tried downloading it again a couple of times but no difference.

Comment: Try uninstalling then run `sudo apt-get autoclean`... And install again...

Comment: Looks like libreoffice-common is corrupt or otherwise broken. `sudo apt clean libreoffice-common`, then try installing again.

Comment: I've tried both those things without success. I don't think it's a problem with the deb file. It's identical to the file used on another machine. And I'm now seeing the same problem on a different machine with a perl file which definitely worked, from the same repository mirror, on other machines.